# \includeonlyframes and pdftitle

Tags: beamer, pdftex

When I use `beamer` with `\includeonlyframes{someframe}`, the resulting PDF has the same pdftitle as the overall document.  Is there any way to set the pdftitle to the title of the `someframe`, the only frame I am including?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\includeonlyframes{frametwo}
\title{Document title}
\begin{document}%
\begin{frame}[label=frameone]{Frame one}
Spam
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[label=frametwo]{Frame two}
Eggs
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Running `pdflatex mini` results in a PDF with title *Document title*. Is there any way to get the title of the only frame that is compiled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the `pdftitle` yourself using `\hypersetup{pdftitle=<title>}` after you disable the use of it by beamer using the `usepdftitle=false` option.

```
\documentclass[usepdftitle=false]{beamer}
\includeonlyframes{frametwo}
\hypersetup{pdftitle=frametwo}
\title{Document title}
\begin{document}%
\begin{frame}[label=frameone]{Frame one}
Spam
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[label=frametwo]{Frame two}
Eggs
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you need this often and/or like to avoid having the name written twice you could redefine `\includeonlyframes` to do this automatically:

```
\documentclass[usepdftitle=false]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\includeonlyframes[1]{%
    \hypersetup{pdftitle={#1}}%
    \def\beamer@framerestriction{#1,}%
}
\makeatother
```

However, I didn't found a way to switch `usepdftitle` off automatically if `\includeonlyframes` is used. With it off you won't get any title for all frames.

Comment: It would be nice to still have the pdftitle if I don't use `\includeonlyframes`. In my real use case I have a little shell-function calling `pdflatex` with `pdflatex -halt-on-error -jobname="frame_$1" "\def\onlyframe{$1}\input{presentation}"` and in my LaTeX-source conditionally call `includeonlyframes` if and only if `\onlyframe` is defined. So then I still need to figure out is if/how to pass `usepdftitle=false` as a late option to `beamer` if `\onlyframe` is defined. I'll look at it a bit more, maybe I can find it out.

Comment: You can use `\PassOptionsToClass{usepdftitle=false}{beamer}`.

Comment: Does this hack work if you pass more than one frame?

Comment: With more than one frame, might the following work?

``\makeatletter``
``\renewcommand{\includeonlyframes}[2]{%``
``\includeonlyframes[{#1}]``
``\hypersetup{pdftitle={#2}}%``
``\def\beamer@framerestriction{#1,}%``
``}``
``\makeatother``
``\includeonlyframes{theframe1,theframe2}{thepdftitle}``